# Como inserir target _blank neste código de java script?

Tags: javascript, html

Agradecia ajuda para fazer abrir as páginas em um novo separador.
Eu tenho este código js abaixo, onde e como se coloca o target `_blank`?

```js
if(result[i]['link']=="") {
  htmlToInsert += "<td><a class='butaoJogar' href='"+urlJogar+"?campanha="+result[i]['betcodecampanha']+"'>Jogar</a></td>";
}
else {
  htmlToInsert += "<td><a class='butaoJogar' href='"+result[i]['link']+"'>Jogar</a></td>";
}
```

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância, mas `separador` seria o mesmo que `aba` na língua portuguesa falada no Brasil?

Comment: Na língua portuguesa do Brasil, quando se trata de navegadores de internet isso [**aqui**](https://imgur.com/3JHlD0y) é uma aba. O mesmo que `tab` na língua inglesa. É disso que estamos falando ou o assunto é [IFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)? De antemão me desculpando pelo transtorno linguístico.

Comment: Isto para dizer que devemos chamar o nome correcto para não criar dúvidas. Neste caso a palavra de origem foi modificada no Brasil, deve sempre chamar-se separador e não uma aba. No inglês, tab é uma abreviatura, não significa aba apenas mas sim aba de separação.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu, eu só queria compreender o seu problema para lhe oferecer a melhor solução. Nada mais.

Comment: Ok Augusto Vasques, eu compreendi e lhe agradeço muito. Mas aproveitei para esclarecer melhor a literacia, onde estou envolvido profissionalmente.

Comment: Agradeço a aula de hermenêutica mas é fora de escopo. O objetivo do site é fornecer ajuda com menos interações possíveis entre os usuários. Bastava um sim ou não para que lhe respondesse,

Comment: Ok... tem razão Augusto Vasques. Talvez isso aconteça devido a uma certa saturação. Daqui para a frente já não vai acontecer, apenas vou responder sim ou não, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target="_blank"` pode ser adicionado aos links da seguinte maneira:
`<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>`.

No seu exemplo, ficaria:

```js
if(result[i]['link']=="") {
  htmlToInsert += "<td><a class='butaoJogar' href='"+urlJogar+"?campanha="+result[i]['betcodecampanha']+"' target='_blank'>Jogar</a></td>";
}
else {
  htmlToInsert += "<td><a class='butaoJogar' href='"+result[i]['link']+"' target='_blank'>Jogar</a></td>";
}
```

Para mais informações pode consultar [este link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).

Comment: Eu estou com dificuldades em decodificar a pergunta, mas eu acho que não seja isso. Acho que o AP só quer saber como abrir um link em uma nova aba e não em nova janela. E se for essa a pergunta seria somente modificando a as configurações do navegador.

Comment: Ps: Não fui eu quem negativou, Não tenho informações para negativar ou positivar. Como já disse estou com dúvidas da minha interpretação.

Comment: Mas o blank ja abre numa aba, não? Agora que vc falou é que pensei que ele pode querer um "pop up".

Comment: As pessoas são mesmo misteriosas... Não gostam de falar o motivo do -1 :)

Comment: Só abre um uma nova aba se estiver configurado pelo usuário.É o comportamento default, mas tem muita gente que faz a alteração.

Comment: Olá, eu quero abrir a página numa nova janela ou separador, por agora abre na mesma janela ou separador.

Comment: Deixei o +1 pois entendi que o AP apenas quer que abra um página independente de onde. Você está correto.

Comment: @Meirelles, sendo assim a resposta foi-lhe útil? Verifique se não estás a trocar `"` e `'`. Como estás numa string é necessário fazer o escaping out usar aspas simples.

Comment: Resolvido, já está a funcionar. Tinha mesmo um erro nas aspas " '. Muito Obrigado Augusto Vasques e tvDias.